# How to highlight navigation menu that refers same URL

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu which has two items refers to same URL.

```
<div id="LEFTmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="app/link1">Page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link2">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link3">Page3</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link2">Page4</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link5">Page5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here Page2 & Page4 points to same URL.

[Update]

how to highlight the selected link/item when user clicks on Page2 or Page4 and after the request is forward to link2. So I cannot do this in click event and use preventDefault on the event.

It's an MVC application, so the request goes to a servlet(controller) and renders a JSP. So Page2 and Page4 is pointing to a same JSP file.

Files:

nav.jsp -- Navigation menu 
link2.jsp -- Contents specific to link2

Apologies for not to provide these details earlier.

Answer (score 1):

On click you can extract the `href` attribute of the current anchor tag and search in your menu for it.

```
$(function() {
  $('#LEFTmenu a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $ul = $(this).parents('ul'),
        href = $this.attr('href');
    $ul.find('a[href="'+href+'"]').css('background', 'lime');

    e.preventDefault(); // do not go to link
  });
});
```

[Working example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yirifacedi/edit)

Comment: @AlexandruMihai the question was "how to highlight the selected link/item when user clicks on Page2 or Page4". The code is for sure an example which may be adopted. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

HTML

```
<div id="LEFTmenu">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="app/link1">Page1</a></li>
     <li><a href="app/link2">Page2</a></li>
     <li><a href="app/link3">Page3</a></li>
     <li><a href="app/link2">Page4</a></li>
     <li><a href="app/link5">Page5</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS

I use `e.preventDefault();` for you to view changes.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  $('a').css('background-color','');
  e.preventDefault();
});
$('a[href="app/link2"]').click(function(e){
     $('a').css('background-color','');
    $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is a working [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/8dnaugbj/2/)

Comment: This won't highlight links with the same target.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer should do the trick if you want to highlight the link you click. But if you just want to highlight the Anchor with a specific `href`, just check for it's `attr`:

```
$('#LEFTmenu a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr("href") == "app/link2") {
    $(this).css("color", "yellow");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var $menuLinks = $('#LEFTmenu a');

  $menuLinks.on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     if ($(this).attr('href') === 'app/link2') {
       $(this).addClass('highlight');
     }
    
     $menuLinks.not(this).removeClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="LEFTmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="app/link1">Page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link2">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link3">Page3</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link2">Page4</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link5">Page5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

You could even take this a step further in your conditional and go pure Javascript, depending on your browser support (IE 9 doesn't support [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)). Not necessary and won't make a huge performance difference but I always like to go without jquery when I can:

```
if (this.getAttribute('href') === 'app/link2') {
  this.classList.add('highlight');
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's a better, more dynamic alternativethan the one above. Here we're looping through all the links **except** the clicked one using [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). If any of them match the current, clicked link then it'll either return `true` or `false`. We then use this value to determine whether we add the class to the link

```js
$(function() {
  var $menuLinks = $('#LEFTmenu a');

  $menuLinks.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var that = this;
  
    var linkHasDuplicate = [].some.call($menuLinks.not(this), function(elem) {
      return elem.getAttribute('href') === that.getAttribute('href');
    });
    
    if (linkHasDuplicate) {
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
    }
    
    $menuLinks.not(this).removeClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="LEFTmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="app/link1">Page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link2">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link3">Page3</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link2">Page4</a></li>
    <li><a href="app/link5">Page5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```